# A basic question on the choice of $\alpha$ in the proof of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I see in a book the proof of Cauchy Schwarz inequality for two vectors $u$ and $v$ goes as follows : The vector $u$ is written as $u=\alpha v + (u-\alpha v)$. Then it finds the $\alpha$ for which the vectors $\alpha v$ and $(u-\alpha v)$ are orthogonal to each other. Putting this $\alpha$ into the inequality $||u||^2 \geq \alpha ||v||^2$ gives Cauchy Schwarz inequality. Now, my question is we choose such an $\alpha$ because only this $\alpha$ we can express in terms of $u$ and $v$. Is this correct ? Or, there is any other reason.

Answer (score 1):

This value of $\alpha$ is chosen because it leads to the desired result; that should suffice. An intuition behind the choice might be that the positive definiteness of the form gives us the most information when we apply it to a vector whose norm is as small as possible; the given choice of $\alpha$ makes $\|u-\alpha v\|$ minimal among all choces of$~\alpha$. In more detail, we have $\langle u-\alpha v,u-\alpha v\rangle\geq0$ for all values of$~\alpha$, each of which gives us an inequality in terms of scalar products involving $u$ and $v$. However if $\alpha_0$ is the value for which $\|u-\alpha_0v\|$ is minimal, then the inequality obtained for $\alpha_0$ implies all the others, so we might as well just retain that one. This is because $u-\alpha_0v\perp v$, so
$$
\begin{align}
\langle u-\alpha v,u-\alpha v\rangle&=\langle u-\alpha_0 v,u-\alpha_0 v\rangle+2\langle u-\alpha_0 v,(\alpha_0-\alpha)v\rangle+(\alpha_0-\alpha)^2\langle v,v\rangle\\
&=\langle u-\alpha_0 v,u-\alpha_0 v\rangle+(\alpha_0-\alpha)^2\langle v,v\rangle\\
&\geq\langle u-\alpha_0 v,u-\alpha_0 v\rangle.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please explain the terms "positive definiteness of the form gives us the most information".

Comment: @user96000: I've extended the answer.

Comment: So, if our goal is to estimate the tight bound for $|<u,v>|$ then this intuitive idea gives motivation. But from the begining we don't know that we are going to get Cauchy Schwarz inequality with this technique. Is this correct ?

Comment: @user96000: I don't understand your question. Our goal is to prove the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. But that inequality has been formulated as sharp as it can, so if one uses a weaker inequality than others that are available to us, it won't suffice to prove C-S. Try it, and you will fail. It is not that they cannot be expressed in terms of $u,v$ as your OQ suggests, it just won't give you C-S. On the other hand the choice of $\alpha_0$ does allow proving C-S. As I said, that should suffice as explanation. I don't really see what you would like to know further about this.

Comment: yes, I understood my mistake. What I wanted to clarify is that $||u||||v||$ is the tightest bound for $|<u,v>|$ because of our choice of an $\alpha$ which makes $||u-\alpha v||$ minimal.